# Connection with MQClient 7.5.0 and SHA2

Tags: unix, ibm-mq, sha2

I have a "blackbox" application written in Java that connects to MQ. On unix server there is MQ Client installation version 7.5.0. Java application is using 1.7.0_79. I have to use `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` to make the connection.

I cannot upgrade to MQ Client v8. I am not entirely sure if I can connect having MQ Client version 7.5.0 and for instance use `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`.

Would be that even possible to establish connection having these components ?

Comment: What specific 4 digit MQ version are the `com.ibm.mq*.jar` files from,  7.5.0.8.  Which provider is java from, IBM or Oracle?

Comment: IBM MQ versions - 7.5.0-7.x86_64, and Oracle Java 1.7.0_79 (build 1.7.0_79-b15)

Comment: This should be possible if you have this java system property set `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` and use ciphersuite value `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`.  Note does not start with `SSL_` for Oracle java.   I can write this up as an answer if it works for you.  Note you need the strong cryptographic provider enable in java to support ciphersuites with `AES_256` encryption.

Comment: I have added everything as you advised. Now when it comes to "strong cryptographic provider enable in java" - I have also added JCE (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jce-7-download.html) is that what you were refering to ? So if I now run applciation I got an error : Caused by: com.ibm.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393 (...) java.io.Exception: Invalid keyStore format - which in my case is pkcs12

Comment: MQ expects jks format.

Comment: Did changing the keystore to jks work?

Comment: It's close but still getting an error : CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771 : SSL handshake failed (..) java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available - this means java itself ? I am quite puzzled as I installed JCE ..

Comment: It worked. I added BouncyCastle JCE as well.

Comment: I received a similar error with older Java 7 versions. I think if you moved to a higher java 7 release or java 8 or 9 you would not need bouncy castle JCE.

Comment: The case is, that this "blackbox" application is running on java 7 and there are no chances it will change. Anyway.. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated !

Comment: Hi Pavel thank you for the feedback, you mention you were at 1.7.0_79, if you moved to 1.7.0_161 it should have the strong cryto provider included and the setting in place to utilize it.  This was not the case at _79.  I did some tests and it looks like up to _131 it was not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM added support for non-IBM Java cipher suite names via APAR IV66840, this was included in MQ v7.5.0.5.

What you are asking should be possible if you have the following:

1. Set this java system property
   `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`
   or
   `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false")`
2. Use cipher suite value `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`.
   Note does not start with `SSL_` for Oracle java.
3. Make sure the strong cryptographic provider is enable in java to support ciphersuites with AES256 encryption.  It appears that if you upgrade to a higher level of java 7 (1.7.0_161 for example) this will be included and enabled by default.
4. Use a JKS keyStore.